# How to get the name of Material UI 'Autocomplete' component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with multiple [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) MUI components and currently trying to write a "generic" event handler that will call `useReducer` hook to store the state.

The problem is that in `Autocomplete` docs, onChange function looks like the following:

```
function(event: object, value: T | T[], reason: string) => void
```

I'm trying to get the name of a field from the event object (to determine what Autocomplete is being changed), but `event.target.name` and `event.currentTarget.name` are not working.

Are there are any ways to retrieve the name of a component that was changed?

Comment: You could do `onChange={callback.bind(null, <your-identifier-here>}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get undefined is that the `event.target` in the `onChange` points to the `li` but the MaterialUi Autocomplete will add the `name` to the outer `div`. So, there is no straight forward way. You can use a `ref` and use `getAttribute` to get the name.

[image: Edit Material autoselect get name attribute]

**Code snippet**

```js
export default function ComboBox() {
  const ref0 = useRef();

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      ref={ref0}
      name="movies"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      onInputChange={(e, v, r) => {
        const ev = e.target;
        if (r === "reset") console.log(ev, v, r);
      }}
      onChange={(e, v, r) => {
        console.log(ref0.current.getAttribute("name"));
      }}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          name="auto-input"
          {...params}
          label="Combo box"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: In this prop - `ref={ref0}` is it possible to choose any `ref` name you want? Like `red={input}` or similar?

Comment: Did you get an answer on whether it's possible to choose any ref name you want?

Comment: Yes it is possible